# Flutter xml to json with error on RssFeed.fromJson and Text(item?.title)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to read an rss feed http://www.tusciaweb.eu/feed/

But I have this error in the code that I can't resolve

> lib/news.dart:27:22: Error: Member not found: 'RssFeed.fromJson'.
> return RssFeed.fromJson(json);
> ^^^^^^^^

This is code with error

```
Future<RssFeed> _fetchFeed() async {
    final response = await http.get('http://www.tusciaweb.eu/feed/' as Uri);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Xml2Json xml2json = Xml2Json();
      xml2json.parse(response.body);
      var json = jsonDecode(xml2json.toParker());
      return RssFeed.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load feed');
    }
  }
```

Sempre sotto ricevo questo altro errore su questo codice

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('News'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _feed,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
            );
          }
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          var feed = snapshot.data;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: feed?.items?.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              var item = feed?.items![index];
              return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(item?.title),
                  subtitle: Text(item?.pubDate?.toString()),
                  onTap: () {
                    // TODO: Navigate to article detail page
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

Error

> lib/news.dart:59:31: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
> title: Text(item?.title),
> ^
> lib/news.dart:60:34: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
> subtitle: Text(item?.pubDate?.toString()),
> ^
> Failed to compile application.

I tried every available solution, but couldn't figure it out. I have these libraries imported into the project.

> share: ^0.6.5+4
> google_fonts: ^4.0.1
> http: ^0.13.4
> intl: ^0.17.0
> animations: ^2.0.2
> xml: ^5.3.1
> xml2json: ^5.3.2
> webfeed: ^0.7.0
> url_launcher: ^6.0.18
> cached_network_image: ^3.2.0
> ionicons: ^0.1.2
> flutter_html: ^2.2.1
> flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2

Comment: `item?.title` is potentially null, so you use it as a `String` (it's a `String?`). You can make it into a `String` by adding a `!` i.e. `item?.title!` but you may get a runtime error if it really is null. It's best to check potentially null values first and handle them differently if actually null - or to assign default values typically with a null aware operator. So: `final myString = myPotentiallyNullString ?? 'my default value';` will definitely be a `String`

Comment: Also, strongly consider using the `xml` package directly rather than going via `xml2json` and then parsing the JSON. Why not just parse the XML?

Comment: Finally, it looks like your `RssFeed` class doesn't have a `fromJson` named constructor - but you don't show the code of that.